# How do I access Cloud Firestore when created as a service within Cloud Platform?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm familiar with using Cloud Firestore when created through Firebase, but I've created a Cloud Firestore as a service within Cloud Platform and I can't figure out how to have a client access that database.  I was expecting there would be someway to generate a `GoogleService-Info.plist` so that my iOS app can access Firestore.

How is Cloud Firestore different when created from GCP, and how can clients access it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access Firestore from iOS, you will still have to go through the Firebase console to add your app to the project and generate that plist file.

What you probably don't realize is that a Firebase project is just like a GCP project.  Every Firebase project **IS** a GCP project, just pre-configured with some services and APIs enabled.  [Read this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f) for a full discussion.  If you created your project via the Cloud console, you can just as easily access the very same project from the Firebase console.

Your Firstore instance is 100% the same, no matter how you access it.  All the same data and scaling behavior that you expect from Firestore.  The only differences lie in how Firebase client apps add special mobile functionality.  [Read this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e) for a full discussion specific to Firestore.

Bottom line is that, for use with mobile apps, you should still use the Firebase console to set that up.  You can use both console together at the same time.  They show almost entirely the same data, but Firebase is simplified for mobile-centric use.

Comment: `If you created your project via the Cloud console, you can just as easily access the very same project from the Firebase console.`

- I don't see my GCP project on https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/ even though I setup Cloud Firestore, is this expected?

Comment: You have to manually add it with the add button.  The ones you see now already have Firebase APIs enabled.